# MongoDB server not starting from vs code terminal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mern

I am a beginner of MERN and while learning Mongodb I used to open my server using my PowerShell by the command `mongod` but I got to know that I can do the same from my VS code terminal. But unfortunately, it is not starting the server for some reason. There is no error that it prints on the screen. It simply prints some data and doesn't start the server. It is running `mongo` command perfectly on my terminal. Can anyone tell me why it is starting?

Comment: Run `mongod` from terminal, then it should show an error. Or have a look at the mongod logfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error got fixed.  Actually my project was in D drive and my data folder was into my C drive so whenever I was opening the terminal using `mongod` command.  It used to find the data folder and as it didn't used to find it on D drive. It therefore used to close it up at the same time. Though if it would have shown the error correctly then it would have been better to fix it up.

I used `cd C:` command to change into the C: drive and then used the command `mongod`